# Set time in alarm to call a method in iOS

Tags: ios, datetime, timer, alarm

I want to create an alarm in my iOS app. I want to set a particular time of the day. I also want to repeat that alarm everyday. When this alarm is fired, I want one method to be executed say at 11:00 am. Does anyone have an example or code snippet to implement this functionality?

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work for my functionality!! I don't want Local notifications. I just want to execute one method.

Comment: You cannot do that.  iOS does not allow you to arbitrarily call code on a timer.  The closest you will be able to do is send a silent push notification from a server (new in iOS 7) and handle your logic then.  However, that seems a bit complicated and you are better off rethinking your logic.

Comment: Isn't there anything in iOS like AlarmManager in Android?